# Filter wont work together with bool

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Iam trying to gather results from elasticsearch with filter. when I added the filter i get unexpected results. (iam expecting to see results that only matched with the terms "Exception" or "Error").

perhaps I placed the filter in the wrong place?

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "message": "error"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "message": "exception"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": {
        "match": {
          "message": "io.vertx.spi.cluster.zookeeper.ZookeeperClusterManager"
        }
      },
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gt": "now-1000m"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not much info here. What is unexpected result?

Comment: Show us the mapping of `@timestamp` and an example of "incorrect" matching document.

Comment: What happens if you add `"minimum_should_match": 1` juste above `should`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your should.

**should**

The clause (query) should appear in the matching document. If the bool query is in a query context and has a must or filter clause then a document will match the bool query even if none of the should queries match. In this case these clauses are only used to influence the score. If the bool query is a filter context or has neither must or filter then at least one of the should queries must match a document for it to match the bool query. This behavior may be explicitly controlled by settings the minimum_should_match parameter